# jquery .empty() conflict with keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is meant to allow a user to type in a message and then press enter to send it. This should clear the box so that the user can type in a new message. The problem is that the standard result of pressing enter (creation of a newline) is occurring *after* the .empty() event....so the text vanishes and is replaced by a newline, which is quite undesirable. How can I circumvent this?

```
  $('#messagebox').keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == '13') {
            send();
            $('#messagebox').empty();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prevent the default action of the `keypress` via [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) (or `return false` from your event handler function, which is jQuery shorthand for `preventDefault` + `stopPropagation`):

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/evakew) | [source](http://jsbin.com/evakew/edit):

HTML:

```
<p>Pressing Enter will clear the text area below:</p>
<textarea id="messagebox" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#messagebox").focus().keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      $(this).val("");
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });

});
```

---

FWIW, I'd probably use [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val) with an empty string rather than [`empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty) to clear the textarea, since `val` is specifically for setting the value of form fields — but if `empty()` is working for you...

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#messagebox').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == '13') {
        event.preventDefault();
        send();
        $(this).empty();
    }
});
```

Comment: Won't this stop _all_ characters being entered in the field? The `.preventDefault()` should be inside the `if` block...

Comment: Yeah, bigggg typo there. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

[demo](http://jsbin.com/ihitev/edit#javascript,html,live)

```
$('#messagebox').on('keydown',function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        send();
        $(this).val('');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: This has the same problem as the original code, i.e., the field gets cleared but then the event's default processing occurs and the newline character is added.